# React not updating when I make changes to this .jsx file. It only happens when I try to make changes on my server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

When I try to make simple changes to this RegisterPage.jsx file, such as changing the text for the headers or labels, my server does not show any of the changes even when I run "sudo npm run build" or "sudo npm start".

If I make the changes on my personal computer, and I am running localhost, I see the changes fine. I am only having these issues when I try to update the file from my Ubuntu Server.

RegisterPage.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { userActions } from '../_actions';

class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                username: '',
                password: ''
            },
            submitted: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        const { user } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            user: {
                ...user,
                [name]: value
            }
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { user } = this.state;
        if (user.firstName && user.lastName && user.username && user.password) {
            this.props.register(user);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { registering  } = this.props;
        const { user, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.firstName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="firstName" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                            <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.lastName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" value={user.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.lastName &&
                            <div className="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.username ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" value={user.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.username &&
                            <div className="help-block">Username is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.password ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" value={user.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.password &&
                            <div className="help-block">Password is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        {registering && 
                            <img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
                        }
                        <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapState(state) {
    const { registering } = state.registration;
    return { registering };
}

const actionCreators = {
    register: userActions.register
}

const connectedRegisterPage = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(RegisterPage);
export { connectedRegisterPage as RegisterPage };
```

If I make changes in the index.html file, they are updating fine and show on every page like they are supposed to, so I know that it is using the correct build.

Edit:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "abc-go-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Yellowcasey/ABC-Go-Website.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

and since it calls webpack, I assume you need that as well.

webpack.config.js:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html'
    })],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    externals: {
        // global app config object
        config: JSON.stringify({
            apiUrl: '/api'
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd generally advise against making changes directly on your server. Regardless, you'll need to show your `package.json` so we know what `npm start` and `npm build` even are.

Comment: @101arrowz Should I just make these changes in my own ide and pull from the repository?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but if you were looking for HMR rather than just hosting, then Alexander's solution will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just add option `hot: true` to **devServer** config.

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
},
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, do you have any other solutions?

Comment: Try to add to webpack config:
 `"output": {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: "/build/",
    "filename": "[name].js"
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for both of your answers, but the problem was actually just because I did not clear my browser cache after updating the server.